# php if condition for two categories

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

i have two categories on main page(index.php) as named (Products and fruits). then i create a new page named(cart.php). in Cart page i want to include my items Either they are from Products category or from fruit category.
 i write following code to add items in my Cart page

```
<?php
$total = 0;

foreach ($cart as $key => $value)

    if(condition){

        $cartsql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$key";
    }

    else(condition){

        $cartsql = "SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE id=$key";
    }

        $cartres = mysqli_query($connection, $cartsql);

    $cartr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartres);

 ?>
```

in above code i have confusion and i cant understand how to write if condition for add items in my Cart either they belong from product category or Fruit category.so any one please help me to write my if condition for particular category chosen from main page and added to Cart page .or there is any other better solution to fix my problem please help

Comment: ??? `else(condition)` ????

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: and please use wpdb for interact with database in wordpress

Comment: What does "condition" represent in the if/else evaluations?
You can also just make the categories variable if you want, ex:
`$category = (condition) ? 'fruits' : 'products';
$select = "SELECT * FROM $category WHERE `id` = $key";`
And lastly, you can make a single query for this, if you pass your array of `keys` into the select, like:
`foreach (...) {...}
$select = "SELECT * FROM $category WHERE id IN (" . array_map('intval', $array) . ")";`

*sorry that code markdown isn't prettier in a comment - hope you get the gist*

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to predetermine different key ranges for products and fruits. In other words, catalog products in a range from 10000 to 19999. And assign fruits to range from 20000 to 29999. Then your conditions check against the allowable ranges.

Another possibility is to return a `$product_code` variable from the shopping cart that represents either 'fruits' or 'products', then:

```
"SELECT * FROM $product_code WHERE id=$key"
```

This might reduce the need to use a conditional here.

Comment: how i return a $product_code variable from the shopping cart ? i cant fix that kindly share procedure for this solution

Comment: With the $_POST variables from the shopping cart <form> input, you can gather several more helpful variables. Some <input> tags can be hidden with values equal to your product types. `<input type="hidden" value="fruits" name="product_code" >`

Comment: More info on hidden inputs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am looking at this the wrong way but you did not actually say what was going wrong.  To me it seems you are having problems coding to detect if either fruits OR products match your critera and then perform a process, if neither match - do something else.  Alternatively it could be the syntax of your foreach

My apologies if I have interpreted this wrong but it is not clear to me if the problem is in the selection, checking the criteria or performing the operation required. But you do say ' i have confusion and i cant understand how to write if condition'

As I am unsure exactly what the problem is I offer 2 possible solutions.

Solution 1
Without writing the whole code for you this would be one solution to actually check if your criteria is matched in either case. Make $fruits or $products 1 or 0 manually and run it to test - either is 1 echoes 'valid', both 0 echoes 'not valid' You can then add your own code for the actual selection and operations.  This is not meant to be full code but just help you with what I understand is your initial problem.

In any case, by using code like this and substituting your own code you can see where it is going wrong, getting the values, comparing them or the desired final operation.

Hope it helps

```
<?php

// Code here to check if condition for products and fruits is valid (set manually in this code to 1 for  valid or 0 for not valid)
$products='0';
$fruits='0';

//Check to see if either fruits or products are valid

if($products == 1 || $fruits == 1)


{

    // perform operation if either or both are valid
        echo 'valid';
    } else {
        //perform operation if neither are valid
    echo 'not valid';
}




 ?>
```

Solution 2
Maybe the foreach syntax is wrong you do not seem to include { ...} to define the extent of the statements.  You include them for the if but not the foreach - Example of code that works below -

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as $value) {

    echo $value. '<br>';
}

unset($value); 
?>
```